# Vi character encoding issue

Tags: vim, encoding, character-encoding, vi, iso-8859-1

I am trying to see the contents of a Finnish text on vi. However, it replaces some letters with numbers. For example, `<8a>` stands for `ä`, etc.

I changed the character encoding to ISO8859-1, however still when viewing the file, it cannot show the umlaut letters. I also tried `:set encoding=latin1` on vi, however it changes to different letters but not umlaut letters. Finally, I tried to replace those numbers with the original letters, but I am getting 'pattern not found' error. I am not sure whether I am doing the substitution correctly though: `%s/<8a>/ä`

Are there any more solution ideas?

[vi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX8KQ.png)

Comment: In Vim there's an `encoding`, a `termencoding`, a `fileencoding`, and a `fileencodings`.  Then there are locales in your terminal, and locales in your desktop manager (or whatever it is you're using).  To start debugging the problem you need to understand what each of these does.  Then you need to set each of them to their proper values.  They're all dependent on your particular setup.

Comment: I tried all of them but still it does not change those weird characters. I ended up with changing them manually. Maybe the file was corrupted. I cannot think of more reasons about that.

Comment: Yeah, your file seems to be corrupted.  `8a` is not a printable character in either `ISO-8859-1`.  It isn't `ä` in `Windows-1252` or `UTF-8` either.  `ä` is `e4` in `ISO-8859-1`, and `c3a4` in `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

Try from command line:

```
vim -c "set encoding=utf8" -c "set fileencoding=utf8" -c "wq" filename
```

being filename the original file you need to open with right encoding.

Comment: It changes the encoding to utf-8. I think ISO8859-1 is the correct encoding for this language. I tried the command, but still it is the same.

Comment: Just choose the right encoding that suits your needs.

Comment: I tried with iso8859-1 being both the source and target encoding. However, it still shows the same strange numbers. The encoding is right, however it still does not show the correct letters. It is weird.

Comment: Have you tried this
vim -c "set encoding=ISO8859-1" -c "set fileencoding=utf8" -c "wq" filename
or this
vim -c "set encoding=utf8" -c "set fileencoding=ISO8859-1" -c "wq" filename
?

Comment: Yes, I tried all combinations. I check the encoding with vim -c 'execute "silent !echo " . &fileencoding | q' filename and it shows latin1, which is correct. However, when I open the file with vim filename, still I see the strange numbers. The screenshot of the vi is given above in the question.